# JavaFX - How do i make a TableView non-focusable?

Tags: java, javafx, focus, tableview

How do i make an entire TableView not focusable?

When i do

```
TableView.setFocusTraversable(false);
```

i can still click the header and focus the TableView. When the table has been drawn and i lookup the header and also do `header.setFocusTraversable(false)` it still does not work. Maybe because `setFocusTraversable` does not work the same as `setFocusable` in Java swing, yet `setFocusTraversable` works for the entire TableView except when i click the header for the columns.

Comment: Do you want to disable it? What is the purpose of making it not focusable?

Comment: i just want to be able to interact with it without losing focus in my grid of textfields

Comment: now that i think about it, is it maybe possible to do something like, go back to last focused object on tableview focus gain?

Comment: Interacting with something typically involves giving it focus, and only one thing can be focused at any one time. So you may need to implement some logic to track what was focused before and return to it when the user is "done".

Comment: hmm but i currently works like i want it to, just by setting focustraversable(false) i can select stuff and use the scrollpane and everything without it gaining focus, JUST only when i click the header it gains focus, without any other coding, have you maybe got an idea how i could fix the header? maybe overlay it with an invisible pane that cant be clicked through? i guess that would be bad practice

Comment: Not tested, but try this in an external CSS file: `.table-view * { -fx-focus-traversable: false ;}`

Comment: does exactly the same as TableView.setFocusTraversable(false)